# Android Emulator Result display

Tags: java, android, xml, emulation

I have created an simple app which has string input(edit text) and displays the string on click of the button using text view. I have used vertical scroll view, The problem is right side characters hidden. Here is the code I used

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView text;
    EditText txt;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dis);
        txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mesg);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public void Display(View v) {
        String msg=txt.getText().toString();
        text.setText(msg);
        //text.setText("yes");
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff000000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:gravity="bottom" >

            <TableRow android:padding="10dp" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/mesg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:hint="Message"
                    android:text="" >
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:padding="10dp" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="Display"
                    android:text="Dispaly" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:padding="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dis"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image: As you see the 's' in says is hidden and also sometimes it happens with text view]

As you see the 's' in says is hidden and also sometimes it happens with text view

Comment: You have declared a finite width with `android:ems` directive (See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ems) for more explanation regarding the directive). Remove this and see how you go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Add **padding** like `android:padding="5dp"` to `EditText`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mesg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Message"
    android:text="" >
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `android:ems` directive from your EditText.